# Trajectory & Orbit of linear system ODE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have $\frac{d}{dt} $**x**$(t) = A$**x**$(t)$ where $A$ is a 2x2 matrix over $\Bbb R$ not dependent on $t$

Since the general solution of this ODE is **x**$(t)=C_1 e^{r_1 t} + C_2 e^{r_2 t}$, I believe the trajectory of any solution for $C_{1,2}, r_{1,2}$ is:

$T_{r_{1,2},C_{1,2}}=${$(t,C_1 e^{r_1 t} + C_2 e^{r_2 t}) \in \Bbb R $x$\Bbb R^n|\;t,r_{1,2} \in \Bbb R,\;C_{1,2} \in M_{2x1}(\Bbb R)$}

The definition of orbit I have is that orbit is the projection of trajectory from $\Bbb R $x$\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$

I've seen some general methods of de-parameterizing a basic system.  But how do I get the phase space here free from $t$?

Comment: Please replace $C_i(t)$ by $C_i$. Assuming that $r_1\ne r_2$, this is correct. Using $r$ and $s$ for these and inverting the system $$x(t)=ae^{rt}+be^{st}\qquad y(t)=ce^{rt}+de^{rt}$$ one can in general write $e^{rt}$ and $e^{st}$ in terms of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ as $$e^{rt}=ux(t)+vy(t)\qquad e^{st}=wx(t)+zy(t)$$ for some $(u,v,w,z)$ and deduce that the orbit is included in the $(x,y)$-set of equation $$(ux+vy)^s=(wx+zy)^r.$$

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  Also, did you intend to write $y (t)=ce^{rt} + de^{st}$?

Comment: How do we know that, for instance, $e^{rt}$ is a linear combination of $x (t),y (t) $?  Are $u,v,w,z $ always just simple constants in this case?  That seems to be my bottleneck

Comment: Cramer systems... One knows that $$x=ae+bf\qquad y=ce+df$$ hence, considering the Cramer determinant $D=ad-bc$, one gets $$dx-by=D\cdot e\qquad ay-cx=D\cdot f$$ which yields $(e,f)$ in terms of $(x,y)$ when $D\ne0$. Then $$u=d/D\quad v=-b/D\quad w=-c/D\quad z=a/D.$$